# How to compare Properties of a Hash Table against an Array of Hash Tables in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, hash, compare

I'm trying to find the best way to return the Hash Tables stored in an Array, matching all the Properties of another Hash Table, which is separate from the Array.

For example, I have the following Array, and Hash Table variables:

```
$myarr = @(
    @{"first" = "A";"second" = "B";"third" = "C";"fourth" = "D";"fifth" = "E"},
    @{"first" = "M";"second" = "B";"third" = "C";"fourth" = "D";"fifth" = "E";"sixth"="F"},
    @{"first" = "A";"second" = "B";"third" = "C";"fourth" = "D";"fifth" = "Z"})

$crit = @{"first"="A";"third"="C"}
```

I need a way to return each entire Hash Table stored in the Array, where all of the Properties from `$crit` are matched. In this example, I would want to see `$myarr[0]` and `$myarr[2]` returned.

I can achieve this by looping through the Properties of `$crit` one by one, and comparing them to each Hash Table in the Array as follows, but I wanted to see if there is a better way to compare the Hash Tables that I cannot figure out, similar to `Compare-Object` with Arrays.

```
ForEach ($hash in $myarr) {
    $match = $true
    ForEach ($key in $crit.Keys) {If ($hash.$key -ne $crit.$key) {$match = $false;Break}}
    If ($match) {$hash}}
```

The end goal for this is to do the comparison with the least amount of memory usage, as the real world application will be comparing hundreds of thousands of these Arrays, containing several hundred Hash Tables, which all have 100+ Properties. Obviously any help getting in the right direction is appreciated, but my goal is to streamline this comparison as much as possible.

Comment: Is this a one-to-many comparison process, or many-to-many?

Comment: @mjolinor one-to-many; One Hash like $crit, compared to many Arrays like $myarr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert the hashes into objects. I've included two possible options

```
$myarr = @(
    @{"first" = "A";"second" = "B";"third" = "C";"fourth" = "D";"fifth" = "E"},
    @{"first" = "M";"second" = "B";"third" = "C";"fourth" = "D";"fifth" = "E";"sixth"="F"},
    @{"first" = "A";"second" = "B";"third" = "C";"fourth" = "D";"fifth" = "Z"}
)|ForEach-Object {New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $_}

# or 

$myarr = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{"first" = "A";"second" = "B";"third" = "C";"fourth" = "D";"fifth" = "E"},
    [pscustomobject]@{"first" = "M";"second" = "B";"third" = "C";"fourth" = "D";"fifth" = "E";"sixth"="F"},
    [pscustomobject]@{"first" = "A";"second" = "B";"third" = "C";"fourth" = "D";"fifth" = "Z"}
)
```

Then start filtering the collection

1. Copy the full set into `$result`
2. Loop over each condition

   1. Use `Where-Object` to filter on this condition
   2. Store the filtered result into the `$result` for the next loop

Code looks like this

```
$crit = @{"first"="A";"third"="C"}

$result=$myarr
$crit.GetEnumerator()|ForEach-Object {
    $result=$result|Where-Object -Property $_.Name -EQ $_.Value
}
$result
```

Output is

```
first  : A
second : B
third  : C
fourth : D
fifth  : E

first  : A
second : B
third  : C
fourth : D
fifth  : Z
```

Comment: I've been testing this solution, so far for my purposes, it is the best fit. My test cases worked well, but when I added a set of real data, I ended up with the correct results, plus a TON of `Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Property'. The argument is null or empty.` errors... I'm trying to identify exactly why this is, and once I filter out the culprit, I'll get some benchmarks of this versus my brute force iteration. Once I have more results, I'll probably mark this as the best answer.

Comment: I noticed also that your data is inconsistent with regards to keys and the properties based on my solution. The `where-object` is the one that throws the error when the criteria key doesn't exist as key of the hash that became a property. I'm not expecting very high performance numbers especially when when compared to brute Force. The piping will slow things down, even if you don't count the initial time of converting the hashes into objects. Small question, where is your data coming from and generates so many hashes that performance is of importance?

Comment: I've actually tried scenarios where the criteria key doesn't exist, and it didn't throw the error, that was one of my first thoughts too. This data is coming from a collection of millions of text files. The files range in size from a couple kb to just under 1 gb, and are delimited in inconsistent ways. What I'm hoping to achieve with this, is replace writing a new regex for every query of these files that is made.  The performance becomes an issue due to volume, but also to allow as many threads/jobs as possible to run simultaneously.

Comment: @DavidWall, without trying to be nosy, have you tried loading the text files directly into objects and not hashtables. I think you already know about the`Convert-From*` cmdlets from json etc. There is even one in gallery for yaml for example. The reason I ask is to optimize on the conversion time from hash to `pscustomobject`. I'm curious and looking for ward for your findings.

Comment: I'm actually using Import-CSV to get these files, which I'm fairly certain does create a PSCustomObject (correct me if I'm wrong here), but in my limited experience, handling this data as I would a hash works for my intentions. I worked out the errors I was getting, and after some tests, your example is ~7% faster, which is accomplishing exactly what I was after.

Comment: Super news then. Haven't thought this out, but it could be that the algorithm could further improve for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Device a basic function to test your criteria against *one hashtable*, then use `Where-Object` to filter the array of hash tables.

For the first part, we could do something like this

```
function Compare-HashtableSubset
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=0)]
    [hashtable]$HashTable,

    [Parameter(Mandatory,Position=1)]
    [hashtable]$SubTable
  )

  foreach($entry in $SubTable.GetEnumerator()) {
    if((-not $HashTable.ContainsKey($entry.Key)) -or $HashTable[$entry.Key] -ne $entry.Value){
      # missing key or value mismatch, we're done here
      return $false
    }
  }
  # made it to the end, must be good
  return $true
}
```

Now that we can compare two hash tables, let's put it to use!

```
PS C:\> $filteredArray = $myarr |Where-Object { Compare-HashtableSubset $_ $crit }
PS C:\> $filteredArray.Count
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps or not, but you can run it against a test set and see if it scales any better than brute-force iteration:

```
$myarr = @(
    @{"first" = "A";"second" = "B";"third" = "C";"fourth" = "D";"fifth" = "E"},
    @{"first" = "M";"second" = "B";"third" = "C";"fourth" = "D";"fifth" = "E";"sixth"="F"},
    @{"first" = "A";"second" = "B";"third" = "C";"fourth" = "D";"fifth" = "Z"})

$crit = @{"first"="A";"third"="C"}

$match1 = '*"first":  "A"*'
$match2 = '*"third":  "C"*'

 ($myarr |% {$_ | convertto-json}) -like $match1 -like $match2 | convertfrom-json
```

You may or may not need that last convertfrom-json.  It should run faster without it if having the result as JSON is acceptable. It will use more memory than the brute-force iteration, but should do an entire array at once, rather than one hash table at a time.

Comment: I like this idea a lot, however for my specific purposes, it does not scale well. With the number of matches I'll need to make in the real world scenario, the like statements would be too cumbersome for me.